# How to prove that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right)=0$

Tags: calculus

I have seen in a mathematics.stackexchange.com thread that to prove that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ one have to prove that the derivative of $\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right)$ is $0$.

But how can we prove it?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that this is _one_ way of proving that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, but there are several others; this just tends to be one of the most convenient.

Comment: And this only proves that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$ is a constant !

Comment: @Yves, this becomes an initial value problem. You show that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = f(x)$ satisfies the differential equation: $f'(x) = 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @Joel: the "proof" just shows that $f'(x)=0$ and the constant remains undeterminate.

Comment: This discussion is nonsense as long as the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are not defined and related to some axiomatic.

Comment: @Yves, last I heard, $\sin$ and $\cos$ were well defined. There are a dozen definitions we could use, and they all lead to $d/dx \sin(x)=\cos(x)$ and $d/dx \cos(x)=-\sin(x)$. That is what you need for this proof. Specifically we could use the Taylor series as a definition and derive the properties $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: @Joel: if $\sin$ and $\cos$ are define from geometry, how do you get to the Taylor expansion ?

Comment: There are many definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ they actually do not depend necessarily on geometry. This is the power of Analysis. You can start from defining: $\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!$ and $\cos(x) = d/dx \sin(x)$ and derive all the properties of $\sin$ and $\cos$ from that.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} (\sin x)^2 & = 2\sin x\cdot\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = 2\sin x\cos x \\[15pt]
\frac{d}{dx} (\cos x)^2 & = 2\cos x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\cos x = 2\cos x\cdot(-\sin x)
\end{align}
$$

Now add those together.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[\cos^2x+\sin^2x\Big]=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[\cos x\cos x\Big]+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[\sin x\sin x\Big].$$
Now use the product rule knowing that: $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin x=\cos x\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos x=-\sin x.$$

Comment: Using the chain rule would also be helpful, taking $f(x)=\sin x$ and we have $(f(x))^2$ to differentiate..

Comment: @Shubham True, we can also use the complex definition of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ or using power series.

Answer (score 1):

First we can see easily that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)=\frac{d}{dx}1$$
and since 
$$\frac{d}{dx} =0$$
Then we can plug it back into the original function to get
$$\frac{d}{dx} 1=0=\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)$$
But if you want to do this from scratch, we can also say that by the linearity of the derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)=\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2 x)+\frac{d}{dx} (\sin^2 x)$$ 
And now by the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2 x)+\frac{d}{dx} (\sin^2 x)=(2(\cos x)(-\sin x))+(2(\sin x)(\cos x))$$
This was the big step, now it's simple algebra:
$$(2(\cos x)(-\sin x))+(2(\sin x)(\cos x))=-2(\cos x)(\sin x)+2(\sin x)( \cos x)=0$$
and that is it! I hope this helps.

Comment: Where you wrote $\dfrac{d}{dx}=0$, you need $\dfrac{d}{dx}1=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score -2):

<sup>I am assuming only the trigonometric definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.</sup>
 $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ can be proved$^1$ by showing that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=0$. This identity is equivalent to [pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Sine_Squared_plus_Cosine_Squared). Pythagorean theorem in turn can be proved with the use of calculus, e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Proof_using_differentials)($\angle EDC$ tends to $\angle BCA$ as $\Delta x$ tends to $0$).

---

$^1$ By applying [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we can show that $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$ where $f(x)=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$. We know if the derivative of a function is $0$ then the function is a *constant*.

So $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=0 \implies (\sin^2x+\cos^2x)= constant\ \  \forall\ x$.
At $x=0$, $=(\sin^20+\cos^20)=(0+1)=1$.

Now  we have computed the value of $(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$ for a certain value of $x$(namely $x=0$), this value will remain same for every other value of $x$, since $(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$ is a constant function.
  So $(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=1\ \forall\ \ x$.

Comment: But that's not the only way to do it.  Whether you can first show that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ depends on which definitions of sine and cosine you're using.

Comment: Can you precise why "This is not true" ? You could totally define sin(x) and cos(x) first, then compute their derivative, and finally use it to show $cos^2 + sin^2=1$. Actually, you can even only assume the existence of two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f'=-g$ and $g'=f$ without introducing series or complex and shows that these functions verify $f^2 + g^2 = 1$ using derivation. (Actually, if $f$ and $g$ are regular enough, they must actually be $cos$ and $sin$ up to some details but you don't need to know it)

Comment: @YannHamdaoui We would have to presume f(0)=0 and g(0)=1.

Comment: I think in proving $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))=\cos(x)$ we use the identity $f(x)=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=1$.

Comment: You're right, we need a few more assumptions to have $f^2 + g^2=1$, but you get my point I think. You're wrong about the derivative though, because the usual scheme for defining $cos$ and $sin$ involves series (from complex exponential for example) and you easily show from there the identity on the derivatives. And by the way, for you, where does the fact that $cos^2 + sin^2 = 1$ come from ? Of course, all these properties are linked, but there is no reason to assume that $cos^2 + sin^2=1$ is more "natural" or "anterior"

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I am using simple trigonometric definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$, that is $\sin=\dfrac{P}{H}$ etc. I do not mean the complex series definition. And $\sin^2+\cos^2$ comes from the pythagorus theorem.

Comment: I see, but I don't think it's a good mathematical definition for manipulating $sin$ and $cos$ as functions. For example, with your definition, can you prove that such functions are derivable (I'm truly wondering, it's not a rethorical question) ? Anyway, even if I understand what you mean, then you should see why stating "This is not true. It is the other way round" is not justified, apart from the fact that any serious formalization of $sin$ and $cos$ uses the serie definition (as much as I know), even for an exercise, you could ask to show $cos^2 + sin^2=1$ from other known properties.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui [This proof](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8d.pdf) is only semi-rigorous, but it does only use geometry.

Comment: @Strants Very interesting, thanks for the link !

Comment: @Strants [Here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8d.pdf) they say:"_As Δθ approaches 0, segment QP gets closer and closer to arc QP a_".  How can we prove this statement?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Could you explain me about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759373/how-to-prove-that-fracddx-left-sin2x-cos2x-right-0/759419#comment1580342_759419). Also I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Anupam It's an approximation that is widely used in Physics. The intuition is that if you take two points on a circle, then the length of the arc linking these two points is greater than the length of the straight line linking them. But if you make your points closer and closer, zooming enough on a little arc, then the curvature is diminishing, and the length of the arc tends to the length of the straight line.

Comment: Formally, if you try for points with $\theta$ and $\theta + d\theta$ with small $d\theta$, line length is $sin d\theta$, arc's is $d\theta$ and it's just saying $sin(d \theta) \approx d\theta$ for small $d\theta$.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I know this. How to prove formally. Like from the definition of a straight line we know that the segment PQ is always shorter than arc PQ. Now we have to prove that the error $\epsilon$ decreases as $\Delta \theta$ decreases and in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.